# Correct way to query LDAP?

Tags: ldap

Inside a software (won't mention the name but I hope it doesn't matter) I have a 'Test Download' button to verify my BASE DN and Filter (Which is optional) is working. Other than about 20 lines, other results aren't shown, so I don't know if what I am doing is working.

I can enter a BASE DN and a Filter.
Am I correct in thinking if I write a longer BASE DN, it will search the results faster and possibly not return quite so much to the application? What I mean by this in example is:

Instead of a short BASE DN like: (Making this up)
`DC=ACME,DC=ds,DC=com`
and no filter, rather do something like:
`OU=Appliance,OU=Groups,OU=DEV,DC=ACME,DC=ds,DC=com`
and then add a filter like:
`"CN=Test Group 2"`
The idea being it won't start searching records (objects?) except within that BASE definition. I would think the search would be much faster in a very large group of items to search.

Follow up question: Can I replace the '2' with a '*' wildcard to return all records from all  the existing 'Test Groups x'?

Thank-You.

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can enter a BASE DN and a Filter. Am I correct in thinking if I write a longer BASE DN, it will search the results faster
> [...]
> The idea being it won't start searching records (objects?) except within that BASE definition. I would think the search would be much faster in a very large group of items to search.

Possibly yes, but depends on the query. While the base DN is a lot like a filesystem path (deeper in the hierarchy = fewer items to search), the filter is a lot like querying a SQL table – some attributes (columns) are indexed, others are not.

So if your query can be optimized by the server down to an index lookup, it will be fast regardless of the base DN (almost); if it uses entirely non-indexed attributes and requires individually comparing every entry, then of course giving a base DN that covers fewer entries in total will make the search faster.

> and possibly not return quite so much to the application?

Depends on the rest of the query. If your filter is written such that it only matches 1 entry, then it only returns 1 entry either way, regardless of how much data the server had to go through.

> Follow up question: Can I replace the '2' with a '*' wildcard to return all records from all the existing 'Test Groups x'?

In filters – usually yes but *it depends.* While most attribute types support either substring or at least prefix match, there are some which don't (e.g. integer-type or DN-type attributes likely don't). For example, filtering groups by `(cn=Test*)` should almost always work, whereas filtering users by `(memberOf=CN=Test*)` probably won't (as memberOf holds DNs, not plain strings, and typically doesn't have a substring match defined for it).

This is also relevant to your performance question. Depending on LDAP server and its indexing configuration, a "prefix" wildcard like `Test*` may be just as fast as an "exact match" filter (if the server supports prefix indexing), or it may be as slow as an unindexed search. And a "substring" wildcard like `*Test*` may likewise be indexed or not.

Comment: Thank-You for your detailed response. You explained why my 'Test*" example didn't work. It's called with a 'memberOf=.' I'm going to need to read up more on LDAP.

Comment: Ah, in that case do two searches – one search to find DNs of all groups matching `(cn=Test*)`, then a second search with `(|(memberOf=DN_A)(memberOf=DN_B)...)` to find all members of all those groups. (And, keep in mind that strings should go through backslash-escaping before putting them in filters – a lot like in SQL – so that a group name with "( )" in it won't break the filter.)